# How to properly instantiate a subclass in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

If I have a `Book` model:

```
class Book < ApplicationRecord
  def calculate_page
    .
    .
  end
end
```

And I create a custom subclass `ExtendedBook`:

```
class ExtendedBook < Book
end
```

How do I instantiate an extended book object that inherits a book instance along with it's instance methods. Something on the lines of:

```
@book = Book.first
@extended_book = ExtendedBook.new (@book, @attributes_for_extended_book)
```

So that I am ultimately able to use the `@book`'s instance methods directly in the `@extended_book` object like:

```
@extended_book.calculate_page
```

,without having to manually define an attr_getter for `calculate_page` in the `ExtendedBook` subclass.

Comment: How does your `Book#initialize` method look like? What instance variables does `calculate_page` use and how are they connected to `@book` and `@attributes_for_extended_book`?

Comment: I feel like what you have now should work....

Comment: It's not clear what the question is--in what context do you want to do this, and why? What's an `ExtendedBook`? Is it just methods you want to add into `Book`? How do you differentiate a `Book` from an `ExtendedBook`?

Comment: "How do I instantiate an extended book object that inherits a book instance along with it's instance methods." – I have no idea what that means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Forwardable`:

```
require 'forwardable'

class ExtendedBook
  extend Forwardable

  attr_accessor :book

  def_delegators :@book ,:total_pages,:my_other_method:,whatever

  def initialize(book)
     @book = book
  end

end
```

and make sure to have an `attr_reader` or `attr_accessor` for every instance variable in `Book` you want to delegate to.

Answer (score 2):

Subclasses automatically get the methods of the parent class.

So, all you would need to do is:

```
@extended_book = ExtendedBook.new
@extended_book.calculate_page # This will work.
```

Now, you might want your extension to be able to play around with an existing @book object. In that case, you don't want a subclass per se, more likely a decorator.

```
class Book
  def initialize(total_pages)
    @total_pages = total_pages
  end
end

class ExtendedBook
  def initialize(book)
    @book = book
  end

  def pages_in_half
    return @book.total_pages / 2
  end
end

book = Book.new(10)
ExtendedBook.new(book).pages_in_half # Returns 5.
```

This way your ExtendedBook can interact with an already instantiated Book object.

Another option is to allow the ExtendedBook to subclass Book, but copy the necessary instance variables in to itself. You might like this approach better.

```
class ExtendedBook < Book
  def initialize(book)
    @total_pages = book.total_pages
  end

  def pages_in_half
    return @total_pages / 2
  end
end

book = Book.new(10)
ExtendedBook.new(book).pages_in_half # Returns 5.
```

Each has pros and cons, so depends on what you want.

Comment: Yes but I want to avoid having to set `@total_pages = book.total_pages` (as in your latter solution) since the `ExtendedBook` class is going to heavily use `Book`'s instance methods and having to store them all in instance variables feels like an overkill. So is having to do that inevitable?

Comment: you can just save the book in `@book` and then use `@book.total_pages / 2` within `pages_in_half` , if total_pages is public or has a public getter